# Equality in QArith

Tags: coq

I would like to use the commutativity propriety from QArith to replace one expression by an other one:

```
Require Import QArith.

Variable q1 q2 : Q.
Lemma l1 : q1 + q2 = q2 + q1.
Proof.
rewrite Qplus_comm. (* Fail *)
```

Is there a way to use the "Qeq" equality as a "=" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q1 == q2` is not the same as `q1 = q2`.  Here is a proof that shows that assuming they are equal leads to `False`, a contradiction.

```
Require Import QArith.
Lemma Qeq_is_not_eq: (forall q1 q2:Q, q1==q2 -> q1=q2) -> False.
  intro HQ.
  assert (H12: 1#1 == 2#2) by (ring).
  generalize (HQ (1#1) (2#2) H12).
  intros H2.
  inversion H2.
Qed.
```

See [Conversion of nat to Q in Coq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714071/conversion-of-nat-to-q-in-coq/32718861#32718861)  where Arthur A A shows that `1#1 <> 2#2`, and explains why.